# NSString to NSDictionary like JSON format

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

i need to convert following NSString to NSDictionary

```
{"type":"1","number":"100","name":"test","sec":0}
```

Can anyone help!

Thanks

Comment: What did you try doing? Is it just JSON like? Will it always be valid JSON?

Comment: what you showd is already a dictionary

Comment: I tried converting directly to NSDictionary like :
NSMutableDictionary *myResult = (NSMutableDictionary *)strMyDict

and then i tried accessing :
[myResult valueForKey:@"type"]

which gave me following exception :
Exception in messageReceived :  NSUnknownKeyException : [<__NSCFString 0xa67f910> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your JSON is a string, get an `NSData` object first:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then turn it into an `NSDictionary` using the `NSJSONSerialization` class:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```